# how to minify files using webpack without bundling

Tags: webpack, gulp, gruntjs, bundler, webpack-4

i want to minify files like html, css, js, images using webpack but i don't want to make a bundle( don't need a single js for all js, need separate as original structure)

Gulp have option to just minify or just bundle the files but i haven't get any tutorial for minification only using webpack.

Comment: webpack is a module bundler, so I don't think you can use it like Gulp etc.

Comment: @chenxsan gulp have option you can choose either one, so i thought i can use webpack like gulp.

Comment: No such option in webpack as far as I know.